# Vectorization operator

Tags: math-mode, formatting

How can I represent the [vectorization of a matrix A](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Vectorization_(mathematics)) (i.e, vec(A))? I am talking about this simple operator:

[image]

Answer (score 10, accepted):

If all you want is getting something like

> vec(*A*)

then `\DeclareMathOperator` is the way to go:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\DeclareMathOperator{\vect}{vec}

\begin{document}
\[
\vect(A)=[a_{11}\ \dots\  a_{m1}\ \dots a_{12}\ \dots\ a_{m2}\ \dots\ a{n1}\ \dots\ a_{mn}]^T
\]
\end{document}
```

One has to choose a different name than `\vec` or `\Vec` because these already have a meaning.

[image]

Comment: spacing around dots isn't consistent.

Comment: @barbarabeeton The best proof reader in the world! Yes, I forgot a `\ `.

Answer (score 0):

Do you mean only obtaining a proper name? E.g.

```
\makeatletter
\def\Vec{\mathop{\operator@font vec}\nolimits}
\makeatother
```

with a standard usage

```
$\Vec(A)$.
```

[image]

Comment: The standard usage, answer you gave mathematically denotes another operator-It is giving an arrow on top of A which isn't what i have asked for. The proper name answer does not compile and is giving an error and displays nothing. I am looking for vec(A) as denoted in the beginning of the third line in here: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Vectorization_(mathematics)

Comment: Wouldn't `\DeclareMathOperator{\Vec}{vec}` (requires `amsmath`) be easier?

Comment: @egreg- your answer worked correctly with what the operator should look like. Post it as an answer and I will accept it.

Comment: @PrzemysławScherwentke No it does not work for me, though the extra large picture you posted, is how it should look like. The answer is too complicated as well, given that i will use it 100's of times in my document.

Comment: @egreg 's answer works absolutely perfectly.