# how to type inverse Vectorization operator ivec() in latex?

Tags: symbols, vector

The Vectorization operator: vec() can be typed

[Vectorization operator](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/115661/vectorization-operator)

how to type inverse Vectorization operator ivec() in latex?

Comment: -1: So when you looked at the linked question, it showed you can do `\DeclareMathOperator{\vect}{vec}`. From what it looks like you didn't even think about `\DeclareMathOperator{\ivect}{ivec}`...

Answer (score 0):

How about if you already declare the $\vect$

```
$\text{i}\vect{A})$
```

Comment: `\vect` is probably a math operator, so spacing will be inserted after `\text{i}`, which is most likely unwanted. Furthermore your example omits the definition of `\vect` which is not defined by standard LaTeX. The `\text` command requires using the `amsmath` package which is also not reflected by your post. -1